# Как в переменной получить конечный результат?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, debian, linux-mint

Пишу на Bash скрипт, ищу файл по имени

```
 RESULT0=$(sudo find /home/text/ -name  "01*" -print)


 echo RESULT0
```

находит но в терминал выводиться полностью путь

> /home/text/01

как можно очистить вывод что бы в переменной было только имя файла "01" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find /home/text/ -name  "01*" -printf "%f\n"
```

Comment: Если речь о файлах то добавить бы ключ "-type f" к вашему ответу.